# Property set to undefined on page reload/refresh

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I have `medications` object as follow:

```
medications: [
 {
    'name': 'abc',
    'id': naks23kn,
    'resident': //this is resident id, resident is another object
     .........
 },
 {.......},.....
 ]
```

I wanted to add another field `residentName` on this object list or is there any way so that I can display `residentName` in the `v-data-table` ?:

```
 medications: [
 {
    'name': 'abc',
    'id': naks23kn,
    'resident': //this is resident id, resident is another object
    'residentName': 'ad' //set this new field
     .........
 },
 {.......},.....
 ]
```

I am using `v-data-table> as :

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="medications"
  :items-per-page="20"
  :search="search"
  class="elevation-23"
>
```

Now I want to add an residentName field based on the resident field. For this I did the following:

```
export default {
data() {
    return {
       medications: [],
    }
},
 computed: {
  ...mapGetters([
    'allMedications', //this is used to get all medication from medication store
    'getResidentsById',
  ]),
},
created() {
   this.get_resident_list(),
   this.get_registered_medication_list();
},
methods: {
  ...mapActions([
    'get_registered_medication_list', //this is used to call API and set state for medication
    'get_resident_list', //this is used to callAPI and set state for resident
  ]),
  getResidentName(id) {
    const resident = this.getResidentsById(id)
    return resident && resident.fullName
  },
},
watch: {
 allMedications: {
  handler: function () {
    const medicationArray = this.allMedications;
    console.log("Created this");
    this.medications = medicationArray.map(medication => ({
        ...medication,
        residentName: this.getResidentName(medication.resident)
    })
    );
  },
  immediate: true
  },
 }
}
```

This is in `resident.js` getter module

```
getResidentsById: (state) => (id) => {
    return state.residents.find(resident => resident.id === id)
}
```

This is setting `residentName` only when the component is created but if I **`reload/refresh`** page then `residentName = undefined` is set.

Comment: You can use vuex store for this purpose.

Comment: @SunnyPrakash sorry I didn't understand, I have stored `medications` in store which in this component I am getting from `allMedications` getter, and I have stored `residents` in store and I am filtering `residents` by `id`

Comment: Man, why don`t you get a populate data from your database?
in your schema you have a realationship between medications and residents. So when you get a medications list, you request will be return a resident object inside each object.

Wich is your database?

Comment: Another things: 
1 - create a new data: { loading: true }  2 - When you finish you "update objects" set this.loading = false 3 - in your component, check if the itens was done. <v-data-table v-if="!loading"> to show your component 4 - you can use async functions and await inside "to wait while your code will be processed".

Comment: @HenriqueVanKlaveren thank you for your suggestion, I will follow it :) happy you helped me to solve it